# Spring bind application properties Map<MyEnum, List<CustomObject>>

Tags: java, spring, spring-properties

I'm trying to bind application properties to a `Map<MyEnum, List<CustomObject>>` in Spring.

I'm aware of following bindings for maps:

```
foo.keyValueMap.EnumKey=value
foo.keyListValueMap.EnumKey=value1,value2
```

which respectively creates a `Map<EnumKey, String> keyValueMap` and `Map<EnumKey, List<String>> keyListValueMap`.

What I try to accomplish is as the titles says, a map `Map<MyEnum, List<CustomObject>>`, where`CustomObject` having multiple properties including a `Set`.

```
class CustomObject {

    private Set<String> set;
    private String property;

    // ...
}
```